# Make sure an elements id attribute is individual

Tags: javascript, jsonp

I just can't fathom the logic, perhaps I'm over thinking it!

I need to make sure a script's `id` attribute is unique before I append it into the DOM.

**Here are some examples to show you what I need:**

If in the `<head>` element I had 3 child `script` elements, like:

```
<script id="script-0"></script>
<script id="script-1"></script>
<script id="script-2"></script>
```

I'd want my new `script` element to have an `id` of `"script-3"`

If I had 3 child `script` elements, like:

```
<script id="script-0"></script>
<script id="script-2"></script>
<script id="script-3"></script>
```

I'd want my new `script` element to have an `id` of `"script-1"` or `"script-4"`

And in this case:

```
<script id="script-1"></script>
<script id="script-2"></script>
```

I'd want my new `script` element to have an `id` of `"script-0"` or `"script-3"`

**Just so long as the `id` attributes of each script element are unique!**

In this scenario, each `script` element is actually doing a JSONP request, and therefore, as it's asynchronous, another `script` element may be added to the `DOM` in the interim and would need it's own unique `id`.

After the JSONP request has received a response it is removed from the `DOM`, hence the gaps in the `id`'s, like `script-0`, `script-1`, `script-3`, `script-4` and `script-6` for example, as the JSONP requests `script-2` and `script-5` may have received a response and been removed from the `DOM`. In this case, I'd like a new `script` element to have either the `id` `script-2`, `script-5` or, worst case: `script-7`.

I hope this is clear enough!

I just can't work out the logic, any help would be very much appreciated!

Oh, and only vanilla JS; no jQuery etc, thank you!

I promise to post an answer to a question on Stackoverflow for every answer posted in reply to this question! Promise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it really necessary to fill the gaps?

I would imagine keeping a running counter and just incrementing it would be easier to work with, especially considering you can have up to [9,007,199,254,740,992](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t/307200#307200) unique JSONP requests:

```
var requestJSONP = (function () {
    var guid = 0;

    return function (url) {
        var id = 'script-' + guid++;

        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.id = id;
        script.src = url;
        script.type = 'text/javascript';

        script.onload = function () {
            this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
        };

        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

        return id;
    };
})();
```

The closure is optional, but it will prevent any other script from altering `guid`.

Example:

```
var scriptId = requestJSONP('/request/resource?callback=handler');
```

Comment: Would `guid` be persistent between calls? I would have thought that  as it was a variable defined inside the `requestJSONP` function it would be reset to `0` each time the `requestJSONP` function was called?

Also, if there was a script element, in the `head` element in the DOM, that for some reason (however remote the chance may be) that was called `script-0`, this code would be ignorant to that and create a script element with a duplicate `id`.

That's if I've read and understood your code right?

Thank you so much for your help so far!

Comment: Sorry, to clarify: if there was a script element in the DOM, with the `id` `script-0` already, before `requestJSONP` was called, the code would be ignorant to this, and append a new script element to the DOM with a duplicate `id`.

If I've understood your code right. Perhaps I was not clear enough, or just not quite quick enough to grasp your code's logic. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @JonathonDavidOates Yeah, it'll persist. But, it's not defined within `requestJSONP`, but beside it within a closure. (it's actually defined by the `return function () { ... }`). But, yes, if another `<script>` has already been created with `id="script-0"`, the `guid` would collide with it, creating a duplicated ID. Easiest solution is to pick a different prefix, something other than `"script-"` that's only used within `requestJSONP`.

Comment: @JonathonDavidOates Also, if you're not too familiar with closures, you can learn about them [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) or on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures).

Comment: To make sure, the first time `requestJSONP` was run, I could check to see if there are any script elements already in the head, and just start the count after that? I could also create a random number, on the first run, and use that to prefix all the JSONP scripts, e.g.: `5267364547-3` instead of `script-3`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script'); // we're getting all scripts from page
var ids = [];
for (i in scripts) {  // iterate by them
    var id = scripts[i].id;  // take 'id' attribute from current script 
    if (id && id.match(/script-\d+/)) {  // check if id matches 'script-...' pattern
        ids.push( parseInt(id.substring(id.indexOf('-')+1),10) );  // take only nomber and convert it to a decimal number, push this number to ids array
    }
}
ids = ids.sort(function(a,b){return a > b;});  // sort array ASC
var lastId = ids.pop();   // take the last value from array
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! Could you just expand what each section is actually doing, so I know how it works and I'm not just copying code! That'd be a great help!